Will the Fedora Silverblue's read-only disk partition be damaged if I run "sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/drive0" from within itself?
'Drive0' refers to the disk where system is installed. Can the immutable system be damaged (meaning can its filesystem that is mounted in read-only, not counting the files that are user accessible, be overwritten)  if I run this command:
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/drive0

Will the root user have enough privileges to access the drive directly and write zeroes to it or will the immutability of the system and other security related mechanisms such as OverlayFS prevent the root user from being able to write to the protected storage partition?

Why do you think the system would not be damaged is the more interesting question. Always assume that all safeties are off when using sudo or running as root.

Which privilege check are you taking about?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What safety nets / security settings do you have in place?
I believe it's possible to configure SELinux in such a way that this might be caught, but don't bet on it!

Also - 'damaged' is a strong word. (Parts of) the disk will be filled with random nonsense. Which may or may not be what you want.
But don't bet on this filling the drive with random nonsense either. Writing to a mounted filesystem is almost guaranteed to have unexpected results.

By damaged, I mean, will the read-only partition of the drive be overwritten as it should not happen with the mutable filesystem?

@infinitieunique Can you please add that last comment to your question?

@Popup yup, done.

You have the file system marked as immutable but the drive itself can still be written to unless you have some kind of hardware protection in place, e.g. a toggle switch to disable disk writes. Yes, your file system will be corrupted.

Partition being mounted with -o ro has nothing to do with dd(1) accessing the device special file in /dev. That partition would be overwritten.

@doneal24 can be written to by who? Can't the root user have limited privileges and only access the drive through filesystem functions? If yes then is that a thing in my specific case (is such a security precaution in place in the Fedora Silverblue Linux distribution)

How will the filesystem functions work if they cannot access the physical disk? As @Popup commented, you might could use SELinux to limit root's access to the physical disk but otherwise root will have full access to the raw device. You can find SAS controllers that have the ability to toggle a read-only state but you'll have to search for these. Not an uncommon feature for USB drives.

@doneal24 I dont know you tell me. Aren't they managed by the kernel and not root user?

Yes, they are managed by the kernel. But how do you expect the filesystem driver to move data between the physical disk and the file system if the driver cannot access the physical disk? The kernel will not be able to tell if a read() call is coming from the filesystem driver or from some other program.

If you access the device that holds the rootfs directly, you will change its contents.
The readonly flag of the filesystem only protects files accessed through the filesystem. As root you can cause unlimited harm by accessing the raw underlying device. You will probably not be able to remount the drive afterwards, but do not rely on this to securely erase the drive.

Well, the question here kind of is: in my specific case, will I access it? Or will the root user not have sufficient privileges to do so?

Unless you have explicit extra security settings, root can access everything in /dev/. I don't know 'Fedora Silverblue', but I doubt it comes with that kind of restrictive settings.

@infinitieunique You can also access the raw disk devices though interfaces in /sys/devices and multiple programs can use the disk signature or serial number for access. Any SELinux rules you write will need to take these into consideration. And, of course, any user who can write to the raw device will also be able to re-mount the file system read/write.

I feel like what we're doing is drifting farther away from the original question. Which was "are the security precautions, that would prevent the damage from direct bit-by-bit disk access by processes, in place in Fedora Silverblue, as they should be, or not?"

If you're explicitly interested in the settings for 'Fedora Silverblue', I suggest that you ask at the Fedora forums.
This is a good resource for finding out general Unix & Linux issues, but anything related to a specific distro is probably too specific.
As I said, I think that it's extremely unlikely that there are any such restrictions, though.

A better question (for this forum) might be "How can I protect my disks from direct raw device access by root, using e.g. SELinux or AppArmor?".
(I don't have any answer for that question, myself. But I would not be surprised if there are plenty of alternative ways of doing it.)
